# Bash error in mathematical calculation

Tags: bash, floating-point

Im trying to put a sequential value into an equation to give an output in a `bash` script for 2 to 12 in increments of 0.5 :

```
for i in $(seq 2 0.5 12);
do;
    r=$((4*pi^2/$i));
    echo "$r"  
done;
```

I get this error:

```
4*pi^2/2.0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")
```

Comment: bash arithmetic is integer only.

Answer (score 3):

To perform floating point calculations on your sequence of numbers, you can pipe the output of `seq` to `awk`:

```
seq 2 0.5 12 | awk 'BEGIN{ pi = atan2(0, -1) }{ print 4 * pi^2 / $1 }'
```

The advantage of this approach is that only a single invocation of awk is only run once to produce all of the output, rather than using a loop and invoking `bc` once per iteration. If you plan on using the value `$r` from your question as an argument to other commands, this may not be a big advantage. If you were going to use the value to perform additional calculations, you could add them to the awk script.

You could in fact do the whole thing in awk using a loop in the `BEGIN` block:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ pi = atan2(0, -1); for (i = 2; i <= 22; ++i)  print 4 * pi^2 / (1 + i / 2) }'
```

To avoid problems with floating point inaccuracy in the loop counter, I changed it so that it uses an integer increment and adjusted the equation accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Use `bc` for that type of calculations. `bc` is an arbitrary precision calculator, more about which you can read [here](http://ss64.com/bash/bc.html).

```
#!/bin/bash

pi="3.14159265359"

for i in $(seq 2 0.5 12); do
    echo "(4*$pi^2)/$i" | bc -l
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash arithmetic does not support floating point numbers.

Use bc instead (i'm assuming pi is a variable ?)

```
for i in $(seq 2 0.5 12);do r=$(bc <<< "4*$pi^2/$i");done
```

Comment: Works in principle, but if you neither use the `-l` option nor an explicit `scale=<n>;` statement in the script, you'll get _integer_ division.

Comment: @mklement0 Yeah i noticed after but others had already posted so i just left it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use bc and 4*a(1) to estimate Pi.

```
for i in $(seq 2 0.5 12); do echo $(bc -l <<< "16*a(1)^2/$i"); done
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement the existing, helpful answers:

Both `awk` (see [Tom Fenech's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29895114/45375)) `bc` (see [Tim Rijavec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2365792/tim-rijavec)) are viable options.

**Which tool to choose depends on your *precision, rounding, and formatting* needs:**

- `bc` performs ***arbitrary-precision* arithmetic**, and you get to **choose** the desired **precision**.

  - At the requested precision, the **result is *truncated*** (in the case of multiplication and division).
  - `bc` has **no explicit output formatting**, but in the case of division (and in other cases), the value of the **`scale` variable** determines the number of decimal places; **using `-l`**, whose primary purpose is to load a library with additional math functions, implicitly **sets `scale` to `20`**. **By default, `scale` is `0`(!)**, which results in **integer division.**
- `awk` uses ***floating-point* arithmetic** (using **`double`** values) with a fixed number of bits that is **inherently subject to rounding errors** (however, this is *typically* not a problem).

  - **`printf` format `%.6g` is applied** on output **by default**, and **rounding** is performed; note that `.6` in combination with `g` means 6 *significant* digits, which is *not* just the decimal places, but includes the digits of the integer portion of the number as well.
  - Set **variable `OFS`** to a different format string **or use `printf` directly** with a format string to change that.

---

Let's apply the above to the case at hand, using a single input value (`2`) for simplicity:

- `awk` solution:

```sh
$ awk 'BEGIN{ pi = atan2(0, -1) }{ print 4 * pi^2 / $1 }' <<<'2'
19.7392  # 6 significant digits (2 before, 4 after `.`), due to default OFMT, "%.6g"

$ awk 'BEGIN{ OFMT="%.6f"; pi = atan2(0, -1) }{ print 4 * pi^2 / $1 }' <<<'2'
19.739209  # 6 decimal places, thanks to custom OFMT, "%.6f"
```

- `bc` solution:

```sh
$ bc <<< ' 4 * 3.14159265359 ^ 2 / 2 '
19 # !! *integer* division, because `scale` is not set

$ bc -l <<< ' 4 * 3.14159265359 ^ 2 / 2 '
19.73920880218131547976 # 20 decimal places: `-l` sets `scale` to 20

$ bc -l <<< ' scale=6; 4 * 3.14159265359 ^ 2 / 2 '
19.739208 # 6 decimal places, as specified in `scale`; !! note that value is *truncated*
```

Answer (score 0):

ive been able to get it to work using this

printf -v "km" "%.4f\n" $(echo | bc | awk "BEGIN {print 4*3.14159265359*3.14159265359/($i)}")